# mod rewrite for resources

Tags: mod-rewrite

im trying to rewrite some urls on my web app, the problem is it rewrites the images/css/js/etc aswell...
my .htaccess:

```
DirectoryIndex engine.php
RewriteEngine On
Options -MultiViews
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ engine.php?link=$1
```

and some example html:

```
<img src="./theme/default/images/img.png" height="50px" />
```

the thing is if i do this: http://domain.com it works, but if i do http://domain.com/test/asd it rewrites the images to /asd/theme/default/images/img.png ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably not a problem with your rewrites per se, it's likely a problem with the src paths used for your resources. No files that exists are getting rewritten. If you are using relative paths, then rewriting the URI to a deeper path (i.e.).

If you are requesting `http://domain.com/test/asd` and the resource is at `http://domain.com/theme/default/images/img.png` then ensure your source path is either fully qualified or `/default/images/img.png`. Based on your description it sounds like the path to the asset is `default/images/img.png`. Since your rewrite makes it appear that you are in a folder called `test/asd`, the path on the domain becomes `test/asd/default/images/img.png`.

Comment: yes, but how do i make it load from the corect folders? and why does it work if i go to http://domain.com/test (here it loads corectly) but if i go deeper in the uri it breaks down

Comment: As I said, you need to make the src value a full path relative to root. You can't really fix this with .htaccess, since you could serve the same page form two different urls at different depths.

Comment: i fixed it, i added a <base href="http://domain.com/ "> in the header and it works...

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
<base href="http://domain.com/" />
```

The BASE element must appear in the HEAD section of the document, before any element that refers to an external source.